# How to start simple game development with Unity 5

Tags: unity, game-design, game-mechanics, unityscript

I want to start developing games with Unity because it's easy to learn, but I don't know where to start.

My questions are:
- Which preparations should I make for a game?
- Are there any tips and tricks for efficient work?
- Do I need special equipment?

Thank you for your response!

Comment: This is a topic that is widely discussed around the internet, my best suggestion and the way I started game developing was just following the tutorial Unity has. Those tutorials offer all the info you need to answer those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a big question. I'll give you a general set of ideas of what to pick up, but do note that the most important thing is to **always be eager to learn new things**. Game development is so big that you will need that to enjoy it.

Here are the main components you'll need to make any sort of a game ( you don't need any special equipment whatsoever ):

**Programming**

You do not need to be an expert programmer for game development. Some roles do not **need** programming skills. I do, however, highly recommend for everyone involved to be capable of scripting.

For being successful as a game developer ( as in writing the code ) - you will obviously need to be an expert in programming. You can start learning at [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/), [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/), [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/), and [EdX](https://www.edx.org/) to name a few.

Even if you're striving to design games - you'll better get good coding skills. You will be the best person to create the initial versions of your designs to show them off to the public or to give your friends/coworkers/testers to play around with ( to gather testing data ).

Nowadays even artists could use some basic scripting to make their life easier - Photoshop scripts, shaders and even some logic can help them achieve the perfect look that only textures might not be able to do alone.

**Game Design**

Play a lot of games. But don't just absorb the story - focus on how the game works and why it works. Build up systems and form ideas for games that already exist.

Prototype a lot - create a lot of mini projects to test different concepts and designs. Gather data and use it to improve them. AB testing and stats are your best friends.

For something more academic check:

- [MDA: A Formal Approach to Game Design and Game Research](https://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~hunicke/MDA.pdf)
- [Daniel Cook's Blog](http://www.lostgarden.com/)
- [Keith Burgin's Blog](http://keithburgun.net/)
- [Game Theory @ Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/game-theory-1/)

**Unity3d**

Unity3d is huge. You should start with the official resources:

- [Unity Official Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

  - Start with [Interface And Essentials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials)
  - Continue with [Scripting](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting)
  - Finally follow along with some of the [Projects](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)
- [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html)
- [Unity Scripting Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/)
- Participation in the [Forum](http://forum.unity3d.com)

There is a lot of places to learn unity from, but those should give you a good start. If you get frustrated with anything - the forums are filled with discussions and people who might prove helpful and [YouTube](http://youtube.com) is filled with great examples you can follow along.

**Fin**

If you've never done any of that before - take it slowly. Start simple and gradually build better games. Find mentors and other people that can help you grow. Ask a lot of questions and make great games!